# IOS UIActivitViewController custom icon

Tags: ios, ios7, social-networking, uiactivityviewcontroller

Pinterest icon not displayed  as red color in uiactivityviewcontroller
[image]

Comment: That was not much information about the actual problem..? What is the problem? Do you want it in the original colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the custom ActivityItem's image Color,  Any color data in the image itself is ignored. 
The document

The alpha channel of the image is used as a mask to generate the final image that is presented to the user. Any color data in the image itself is ignored. Opaque pixels have a gradient applied to them and this gradient is then laid on top of a standard background. Thus, a completely opaque image would yield a gradient filled rectangle.

For iPhone and iPod touch, images on iOS 7 should be 60 by 60 points; on earlier versions of iOS, you should use images no larger than 43 by 43 points. For iPad, images on iOS 7 should be 76 by 76 points; on earlier versions of iOS you should use images no larger than 60 by 60 points. On a device with Retina display, the number of pixels is doubled in each direction.